# Proper way to connect FedEx Web Services and SaaS

Tags: fedex

From what I learned so far the FedEx require each customer to sign up for [FedEx Web Services](http://www.fedex.com/us/developer/) which is very developer specific and not quite obvious for certain customers.

I'm curious if there is a better way to connect FedEx services with a hypothetical SaaS product?

Answer (score 0):

You need to become a FedEx Certified Developer. It's a very time-consuming process. When you request web service credentials they ask very specific questions about inside/outside development. Based on these questions you should be able to get in contact with the proper department.